# Create amount of recyclerViews set by a string?

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-recyclerview

I'm receiving a `String` with a number from a **TCP Server** to my **TCP Client**, that `String` specific the number of cash registers online and for every cash register i have to create a `cardView`, i created a `cardView`and the `recyclerViewAdapter` but for now the one who set the amount of cash registers is me by adding string in the `ArrayList`.
The `String` send by **TCP Server** is yet set as static in **MainActivity** but now i don't know how can i use it for create the desired amount.

Here is the **code** where i evoke the `recyclerViewAdapter`:

```
public class help extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList selfList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    ImageButton home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.casa);

    initViews();

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         finish();
        }
    });
}

private void initViews(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = 
(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewSelfMachine);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = 
new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    selfList = new ArrayList<>();
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°1");
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°2");
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°3");
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°4");
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewSelf(selfList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: call your intiviews() after you get the string having number from server. After that run a loop and add a item to the list for every iteration. Then pass that list to your adapter.

Comment: could you make an exaple of the loop in code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// after you receives the string from your server

```
String num = serverValue;

int limit = Integer.valueof(num);

selfList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
    selfList.add("" + i);    // add "" with i if you want list with string type
}

// call your init method here
initViews();


// your init method
private void initViews(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = 
    (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewSelfMachine);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = 
    new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewSelf(selfList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```